# Simple Derivation of Functional Equation Question (L'Hospital's Rule)

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, functional-equations

First, the question is:

> $f$ is a differentiable function and $f : R \rightarrow R$
>
> $xf(x)-yf(y)=(x-y)f(x+y)$
>
> $f'(2x)=?$

My approach for problem is using L'Hospital's rule:
$$ \frac{xf(x)-yf(y)}{x-y}=f(x+y) $$
Assuming $y=x$
$$ \lim_{y\to{x}} \frac{xf(x)-yf(y)}{x-y} = f(2x)$$
Taking the limit using l'hospital's rule:
$$ (yf'(y)+f(y))|_{y=x} = f(2x) $$
Taking the derivative of both sides:
$$ f'(x)+xf''(x)+f'(x)=2f'(2x) $$
But the answer is $f'(2x)=f'(x)$

How is this possible?

Comment: Could it be that $f$ must have the form $f(x)=ax+b$? (All such functions satisfy the functional equation.)

Comment: @mickep thanks, but what's wrong with my solution? Is there a way not using functional equation techniques ie. finding the function? Maybe a calculus route?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if $f$ is as I wrote above, then $f''(x)=0$, and thus $2f'(x)=2f'(2x)$, so the statement follows. I have to sleep, but I'll have a look at this problem tomorrow again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In equation
$$
xf(x)+yf(y)=(x-y)f(x+y),
$$
differentiate with respect to $x$ to get
$$
xf'(x)+f(x)=(x-y)f'(x+y)+f(x+y).
$$
Now, set $y$ to $x$ and to $-x$ to deduce that
$$
xf'(x)+f(x)=f(2x)=2xf'(0)+f(0),
$$
which proves that $f(x)=xf'(0)+f(0).$

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks.